# Any way we can evaluate the infinite power tower where it diverges?

Tags: lambert-w, power-towers

When you have:

$$x=y^{y^{y^{y\dots}}}$$

You have:

$$x=e^{-W(-\ln(y))}$$

**ONLY** when the power tower converges.

But what about when it doesn't?  Is there any way to justify $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}=e^{-W(-\ln(2))}\approx 0.82467854614-1.56743212384$?

Can we evaluate it in some analytical way or something when it doesn't converge, sort of like divergent summations and principal values?

Also, if you are simply going to argue that $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}=\infty$, then I argue that I am asking about a way to make the evaluation non-infinite, much like how Ramanujan's summation method allows us to evaluate $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac1{12}$.

While it doesn't make "sense" because we see that it diverges to infinity, I was wondering if we could apply a similar method so as to get a finite value when the infinite power tower diverges to infinity.

Comment: It is possible to justify $e^{-W(-\ln(2))}\approx-0.571624 + 1.086461i$ with the extension of the Lambert's W(x) function in the complex domaine $(x<-e^{-1})$. But $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}=e^{-W(-\ln(2))}$ is false because $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}=\infty$. The Relationship between $y^{y^{y^{\dots}}}$ and $e^{-W(-\ln(y))}$ is derived from the equation $x=y^x$ wich is false if $y>e^{1/e}\approx 1.444668$ -

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank you for your input, but I already knew most of that.  I'll try and edit my question and see if you can add in some ideas.

Comment: How did you arrive at the number $-0.571... + 1.086... i $? I tried your input at Wolfram Alpha and even several variants without getting even near to that value.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I think I used google's calculator.

Comment: If you don't show a reliable/reproducable source for your curious constant $-0.57...+1.086...i $ or correct it I assume you're no more/not at all interested in that question and I'll downvote and propose to close.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Where is your calculator?  I can't seem to find a calculator that calculates $W(-\ln(2))$ at the moment.

Comment: Try wolfram-alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(-LambertW(-ln(2)))   Perhaps "google" can do the same, but I do not know how to ask the google-calculator for the LambertW

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thank you.  Fixed it.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The damage the "equation" you mention caused is overhelming! Many readers actually believe that it makes sense in the usual way, which is of course absurd. Such an "equation" should never be mentioned without explicitely pointing out what is going on. Personally, I do not see a sense to invent finite expressions for diverging series, and to accept that a power tower of infinite many $2$'s is finite just because we can insert $2$ in a formula for infinite power towers, is strange.

Comment: @Peter :-P sorry, my bad :-)  I try not to be trouble myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there can ever be a justification of a finite value for the notation $2^{2^{2^\cdots}}$ . But in fact in most cases, when we talk about tetration we see the things different, namely in form of an exponential tower, which ***begins*** with some value $x_0$ and puts an ***exponential base*** to it. So that, for the case of tetration, we should always write:
$$ \begin{array} {r} \large x_0\\ 
  \large {\,_2x_0 }\\
  \large{\,_{\,_2}} \large {\,_2x_0 }\\
{\,_{\,_{\,_\ldots}}}  \large{\,_{\,_2}} \large {\,_2x_0 }\\ 
  \vdots \end{array}$$
(but which is difficult to model in $ \LaTex $)

With this we can write our beloved infinite towers and setting $x_0$ to the fixpoint near $\small 0.82467854 + 1.56743212 î $ $\,^{[1]}$ has then even a sensical interpretation (and reflects the *infinite* , let's call it now for distinction from the powertower, *"exponential-tower"*).

$^{[1]}$ *which is what also WolframAlpha gives for $e^{-W(-\ln(2))}$*